Quartz.net: Prevent Scheduled Job from Running When Computer is Inactive in C#
I have a Windows service written in C# that uses Quartz.NET for job scheduling. The service is designed to run a job at regular intervals. A minimal version of my code:
// ... 

protected override async void OnStart(string[] args) {
    // ... 

    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<GetNetworkDataJob>()
        .WithIdentity("GetNetworkDataJob", "DefaultGroup")
        .Build();

    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("GetNetworkDataJobTrigger", "DefaultGroup")
        .StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
            .WithIntervalInMinutes(5)
            .RepeatForever())
        .Build();

    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
}

// ... 

I want the scheduled job to not run when the computer is not active, i.e., if it is hibernating or if it is locked. I've tried using query user but that doesn't work because the Windows service doesn't have a user. I've also tried using the Cassia library, and monitoring the power state using SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged, and checking the screensaver state, but none of these approaches have been successful in this context.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can prevent the scheduled job from running when the computer is not active?

Have you tried calling the GetLastInputInfo Win32 API?

My understanding is that that can only be called from the perspective of a logged in user, and a service running outside that can't see that information. It's be great if I was wrong. I might be allowed to run the service as a logged in user (I need to ask the grownups in IT), but if I am, query user gives me the state directly.

Ah yes, you could be right there. In that case the service would need to run as the current user.

@Ben you could try the code from this answer. It will detect if the computer gets locked or unlocked, which you can then use to pause and resume jobs, i.e jobsscheduler.PauseJob(jobJey); / scheduler.ResumeJob(jobKey); or scheduler.PauseAll(); / scheduler.ResumeAll();

This is a cut down version of what I ended up using. As a caveat, I'm not really a C# person, so this might hurt your eyes, but it works.
The approach is thanks to the comment from @Ortega, there's a SystemEvents.SessionSwitch event that I can listen for. So the program.cs kicks off that listener service. If the computer changes session state, it locks the mutex.
Then, when the job is triggered, the first thing it does is check the state of the mutex. If it's locked, don't run the task, otherwise do.
program.cs
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace MyService
{
    [SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {

            var sessionSwitchService = new SessionSwitchService();

            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyService() };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

        }
    }
}

SessionSwitchService.cs
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;
using System.Threading;

[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
public class SessionSwitchService
{
    private Mutex myMutex;

    public SessionSwitchService()
    {
        bool createdNew;
        myMutex = new Mutex(false, "LockStatusMutex", out createdNew);
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += SystemEvents_SessionSwitch;
    }

    private void SystemEvents_SessionSwitch(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Reason)
        {
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock:
                myMutex.WaitOne();  // Lock the mutex when the session is locked
                break;
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock:
                myMutex.ReleaseMutex();  // Release the mutex when the session is unlocked
                break;
        }
    }
}

MyJob.cs
using Quartz;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyService.Jobs
{
    public class MyJob : IJob
    {
        private Mutex myMutex;

        public MyJob()
        {
            myMutex = Mutex.OpenExisting("LockStatusMutex"); // Open the existing mutex
        }

        public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            // Check if the mutex is locked
            if (!myMutex.WaitOne(0)) { return Task.CompletedTask; }

            // Do the work
            console.WriteLine("doing something that shouldn't run if the computer is locked");

            // Release the mutex
            myMutex.ReleaseMutex();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}

I'd be interested to hear if this prompts other, better, ways to solve this problem.
